# SharePoint 2013 always creates new elements in top level folder of Document Library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, document-library

I have a problem with SharePoint 2013. I'm currently setting up a basic collaboration sceanario with SharePoint. I therefore created a basic document Library whith an additional folder derived content type to be used at the top level of the document library. This content type has some additional metadata. Inside of these specialized folders I want to use standard files and (sub)folders.

At first, I had no problem of creating elements and subfolders inside of my top level folders using the standard buttons (Upload File, New Folder) in the ribbon. However, now without knowing what caused this behaviour, when I try to create elements inside of existing folders, SharePoint always creates new elements at the top level of the document library.

Does somebody have an idea what might have caused this beaviour and how to fix it (without code)? I did not find any solution searching the web. Any Help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

P.S. I know that using folders in SharePoint is not recommended in general but I would really like to understand what could have caused the described problem.

Comment: "I know that using folders in SharePoint is not recommended in general" that's what stupid people say. Both Folders and Metadata have their pluses and minuses.

Answer (score 0):

How you are adding the file? When you are adding any document in the library there is a path mentioned in the dialogue box where the files will go and reside. check if the path is correct or not. Might be you are adding in wrong way.Also go in Views and see you have selected the option as **Show in Folder** option.

And yes Folder not recommended in SharePoint...is what Stupid people say.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. Maybe I can give an example, In my Document Library I created several elements of type let's say MyFolder (deriven fom folder content type). I'm using the standard AllDocuments View not limited to folders. When I am inside of such an MyFolder an I try to create a Document or a regular folder using "Upload File" or "Ne folder" in the File ribbon, these new elements are created in the Document Library  top level on the same level as the MyFolder objects.

Library

Comment: Modify the AllDocuments view, and check if it is being selected as Show in Folder or Show without Folder

Comment: For the AllDocuments View, the "show items inside folders" option is set. Is that the option that you mean?